# Pass correct context to function in dialog data in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a service and a component. In the service I am trying to open a dialog in which I am passing a reference to a method that exists in the service. For example:

```
export class SomeService {
   private test = 10;

   public getTest() {
      return this.test;
   }

   openDialog() { 
      const dialogRef = someExternalService.open(MyComponent, {
      disableClose: true,
      data: {
        someData: 'hello world',
        test: this.getTest
      }
    });
}

export class MyComponent {
   constructor(@Inject(DIALOG_DATA) data: any) { 
       console.log(data.data.someData); //prints 'hell world' correctly
       console.log(data.data.test()); //prints undefined.. 
   } 
}
```

The issue is that when that `test` method is called, the `this` in the function is considered to be `data.data`, and not the `SomeService` context.

How can ensure that `getTest` is called with the right context?

**Edit**
I solved by passing `this` as `that` to the `data`
So for example,

```
  data: {
    someData: 'hello world',
    test: this.getTest,
    that: this
  }
```

And then calling it like
`data.data.that.getTest()` which prints correctly, but I feel that I could do it without passing the whole Service object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the **JavaScript Arrow Function** to declare your function. Besides providing a concise syntax to write functions, the arrow function frees you from the binding of **this** keyword. Here is an explanation from w3schools

> In **regular functions** the this keyword represented the object that called the function, which could be the window, the document, a button or whatever.
>
> With **arrow functions** the this keyword always represents the object that defined the arrow function.

Your code would get modified like this

```js
export class SomeService {
   private test = 10;

   public testFunc = ()=>{
      return this.test;
   };

   openDialog() { 
      const dialogRef = someExternalService.open(MyComponent, {
      disableClose: true,
      data: {
        someData: 'hello world',
        test: this.testFunc
      }
    });
}

export class MyComponent {
   constructor(@Inject(DIALOG_DATA) data: any) { 
       console.log(data.data.someData); //prints 'hell world' correctly
       console.log(data.data.test()); //prints undefined.. 
   } 
}
```

Please find the [details here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions).

Thanks.